# How setup sbt for parallel package into jars?

Tags: jar, package, sbt

I have sbt project with several modules that need to be packaged into jar archives. As I see in logs sbt packages each project into jar sequentially:

```
[info] Packaging C:path\target\scala-2.11\projectFirst ...
[info] Packaging C:path\target\scala-2.11\projectSecond ...
[info] Packaging C:path\target\scala-2.11\projectThrird ...
```

Projects do not depend of each other and can be packaged in parallel. Is there a possibility to setup sbt to package projects in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

In sbt [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Parallel-Execution.html) we can find following sentence:

> By default, sbt executes tasks in parallel.

I prepared experiment to check this. I created project with 4 subprojects. This is a code:

main build.sbt:

```
lazy val sub1 = project

lazy val sub2 = project

lazy val sub3 = project

lazy val sub4 = project

Keys.`package` in Compile <<= (Keys.`package` in Compile).dependsOn(Def.task {
})
```

sub1/build.sbt

```
Keys.`package` in Compile <<= (Keys.`package` in Compile).dependsOn(Def.task {
    for( a <- 1 to 2){
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println( "SubProject 1: " + a );
    }
})
```

In sub2, sub3 and sub4 build.sbt is almost identical as in sub1. I changed only number of iterations and printed number. 
I received following output:

```
> package
SubProject 4: 1
SubProject 1: 1
SubProject 4: 2
SubProject 1: 2
SubProject 4: 3
SubProject 3: 1
SubProject 4: 4
SubProject 3: 2
SubProject 4: 5
SubProject 3: 3
SubProject 4: 6
SubProject 3: 4
SubProject 4: 7
SubProject 2: 1
SubProject 4: 8
SubProject 2: 2
SubProject 4: 9
SubProject 2: 3
[info] Updating {file:/D:/sbt/abc/}sub1...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
SubProject 4: 10
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/D:/sbt/abc/}abc...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/D:/sbt/abc/}sub3...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/D:/sbt/abc/}sub2...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
SubProject 4: 11
[info] Done updating.
[info] Packaging D:\sbt\abc\sub1\target\scala-2.10\sub1_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging D:\sbt\abc\target\scala-2.10\abc_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging D:\sbt\abc\sub3\target\scala-2.10\sub3_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging D:\sbt\abc\sub2\target\scala-2.10\sub2_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
SubProject 4: 12
SubProject 4: 13
SubProject 4: 14
SubProject 4: 15
SubProject 4: 16
SubProject 4: 17
SubProject 4: 18
SubProject 4: 19
SubProject 4: 20
[info] Updating {file:/D:/sbt/abc/}sub4...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Packaging D:\sbt\abc\sub4\target\scala-2.10\sub4_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
```

So there are four subprojects. In every subproject 'package' task depends on created task (which prints and sleeps in a loop). When I execute 'package' command then then this task is executed for wach sub-project. But for each one the dependent task is called. As we can see in output these dependent tasks run pallalelly but only two at a time. This coresponds to following sentence from doc:

> (Although never exposed as a setting, the maximum number of tasks running at a given time was internally configurable as well.)

Following three lines from output:

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
SubProject 4: 10
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
```

provide proof that packaging task from one subproject runs parallelly with dependent task from other subproject.

Comment: This is **compile** goal, **not** assembly which package projects. :) Also, whn I see process explorer there 4 high cpu load area in graph, so archives are packaged sequentially